# Cannot start React Native on Android Studio Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I just started with React Native and I have a problem about running react native project, other projects are running normally but this project doesn't work and it doesn't give me any specific error.
When I build on android, application suddenly killed right after start.
When I "react-native run-android"

This picture show is loading
[image]

and then
[image]
[image]

the console
[image]

it took me hours to fix it but still don't know why
can somebody help me?
have a nice day guys

Answer (score 1):

add In the android/app/build.gradle

```
implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.9.0"))
```

source: https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom/issues/441

Comment: Thank you so much but it still not woking

Comment: make sure your application run mobile device properly fine or same problem like as emulator?

Comment: yess @vishu , actually I run mobile app of this repo("https://github.com/jamalag/webrtc-part-7"). the repo of this video ("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yj2pETkKWC8&list=PL_YW-znSZ_dK365WaVuiBUN6FYc9_1hni&index=9"). I install react native to run but I cannot run it and i'm trying to figure out how to run it

Comment: confirm that your targetAPI version follow to your Android emulator version android/build.gradle